# Limit number of file watched with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script written in `nodejs` with `chokidar` where I listen into a folder when a file is added.

When a file is added start a function with many loop.

Sometimes the system add 100 or more files at the same time so the event `add` is called 100 times and the server can crash.

Is there a way to limit watched file and the others wait until watched file are closed?

For example I decide that I can't watch more than 10 files at the same time, the other files wait until first 10 finished their thing.

Is possible?

This is my script:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var folder = process.argv[2];
var watcher = chokidar.watch('tmp/xml/' + folder + '/', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});
watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {
    var filenameArr = path.split('/');
    filename = folder + '/' + filenameArr[filenameArr.length - 1];

    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
    exec('bin/cake manager readXmlAndSave ' + filename, puts);
})
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, your code decides what to do when `add` is called.

Comment: ok so how can I limit in nodejs to 10 the maximum number of simultaneously function called with exec?

Comment: simply add them to a queue and process the queue with your desired amount of parallel ops.

Comment: Which error message do you get when the server crashes?

Comment: server crash and is offline @MehdiElFadil

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri please add the produced crash output with error message to your question.

Comment: Ok so can you explain how to create a queue and process it using my script? The theory is clear, but I do not know how to apply it @KevinB

Comment: Ok but if I have make a question is to receive an help I think because I don't know how to do it or if there is already a modules to make what I want.. @KevinB

Comment: How about using a search engine, or [asking better](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Quite a few factors may generate the crash. There must be some error log somewhere. Read also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const async = require("async");

[...]

let taskQueue;
const watcher = chokidar.watch('myPath');
watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {
    taskQueue.push({path});
})

// handle files 10 per 10 to avoid to exhaust critical resources
taskQueue = async.queue(async function(task) {
  await myAsyncHandler(task.path);
}, 10);

taskQueue.error(function(err, task) {
  handleError(err, task);
});
```

For my culture I'd love to see a pure vanillaJS answer using for example streams and backpressure